# how to make activity can be scrolled vertically if I have view pager that has recycler view in it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

here is the simple project of this problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fs7ggSdhPbiNCWa5GIb5RIIOEKQbgo57/view?usp=sharing

in my activity, as a base, I have tab layout and view pager like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null">


    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout_main" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the code for my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var tabLayout : TabLayout
    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_main)
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager_main)

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) 
        adapter.addFragment(AFragment(),"Fragment A")
        adapter.addFragment(BFragment(),"Fragment B")

        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }
}
```

in one fragment of my viewpager (fragment B), there is a recycler view inside fragment B.

here is the xml for fragment B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.BFragment" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the problem .....

if I scroll vertically in that recycler view in fragment B, it does not make my tab layout in my MainActivity scrolled. the tab layout still on the top. I want to make that tab layout scrolled and disappear from the screen when I scroll the recycler view.

I have tried to set nested scroll view in my MainActivity xml, like this code below, it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_verified_user_control"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout_main"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tabRippleColor="@null">
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager_main"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout_main" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

java or kotlin is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your TabLayout inside a CoordinatorLayout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/id_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```